# Remove from right or left of character

Tags: text, file-io

Is there a way to find a given character in a line of test i.e. `,` and erase everything from the left or right of the character? The text before and after the `,` are of different lengths.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is.

Comment: Without additional details, this is the only possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: You have a string like x = "some,really,cool,string" that is guaranteed to contain at least one comma and you want to erase everything to the left of the first comma in Python.

```
>>> x = x[x.find(","):]
>>> print x
,really,cool,string
```